# DQL Request with LeftJoin

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I want to count how many times my theme is used in my Blog.

Any blog posts (articles in french) can use one or more theme.

So I have a table (ManyToMany) :

- themes_articles (id_theme,id_article) And :
- theme (id_theme,nom_theme)
- articles (blog posts) (id_article, description ...)

In SQL, I do :

```
SELECT T.id,nom_theme,count(A.themes_id) from themes_articles A right join themes T on T.id=A.themes_id group by nom_theme
```

It works, but when I want to use right join in DQL, it's a little bit hard. I switched my two tables for use a left join but I don't know how I can use my relation table here (themes_articles).

I tried something like this :

```
 $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('')
->select(array('T.id', 'nomTheme', 'count(A.themes_id) as nombre'))
->from('themes', 'T')
->leftJoin('themes_articles', 'A', 'WITH', 'T.id= A.themes_id')
->groupBy('nom_theme');
    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

But it doesn't work.

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 93 near 'themes_articles': Error: Class 'themes_articles' is not defined.
```

How can I do to convert my SQL request in DQL request ?

Thank you a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder()
   ->select(array('t.id', 't.nomTheme', 'count(ta.themes_id) as nombre'))
   ->from('<YOUR BUNDLE>:<Theam Entity Class>', 't') //Like AcmeTheamBundle:Themes
   ->leftJoin('t.themes_articles') 
   ->groupBy('t.nomTheme'); //better to use theam id
   return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your request but I have this error
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 87: Error: Expected end of string, got 'BlogBundle:Themes'

Comment: Where is located your Entity ? Please provide this path

Comment: Please send your entity file path

Comment: Like this // src/Acme/AppBundle/Entity/Product.php

Comment: I added my relation name in my request, and it works ! Thank your for your help

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit better ! I had to add the name of the relation between Articles and themes (contient) in my request.

```
  $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
   ->select(array('t.id', 't.nomTheme', 'count(ta.id) as nombre'))
   ->leftJoin('t.contient', 'ta', 'WITH', 't.id= ta.id') 
   ->groupBy('t.nomTheme'); //better to use theam id
   return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```